# Layout get disturb by using dispatcher in action..?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a problem in Struts 2.

Using jQuery and CSS template in my web project .

Problem: When using dispatcher in struts.xml, layout of my project get disturb means jQuery didn't work fine,but at same time when using redirect in xml file..its work fine for me, but by using redirect I did not get default behaviour of struts means I have to pass parameter from action to jsp with url.

like this

```
<result type="redirect">index.jsp?username=$username</result>
```

I want the default behaviour and my layout remain same.

Comment: Post some code most importantly the relevant JSPs also  struts.xml/action class may be useful. If we can't tell why your layout is being disrupted it's hard for us to propose a solution.

Comment: i do not see any relation of dispatcher result with layout getting disturbed, moreover need more information about JSP and what all you are doing

Comment: Press the edit button and add paste that code into the question. Highlight that code and press the '{}' button which will make the code visible (generally spaces code blocks in four spaces).  There are a lot of questions to answer, readability helps us.

Comment: What do you mean "by using redirect you don't get the default behavior of Struts 2"? What behavior do you think you didn't get? The dispatcher has absolutely *nothing* to do with any client-side functionality--if there's an issue it means you're probably configured incorrectly, using bad paths for your JS and/or CSS files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

create a new jsp file say call it css_js.jsp, then include this file in your pages, so that when you move from pages to pages your layout remains same.

In case you are using tiles then in the mainLayout.jsp you can include all your required js and css files

Comment: thanks dear.. i have already follow the same..but the problem is i have a masterpage in which i embedded a slider n i am including another jsp page in masterpage...named eg- addUser.jsp.... In my addUser.jsp i have a another jquery for datetime picker. when i redirect from struts.xml..all working fine...but when i dispatching(default action) then datetime query not work fine for me....

Comment: say your masperpage is not going to be unloaded in that case add the datetime picker js also in masterpage, if it is getting unloaded then you will have to add jQuery.js and datetimepicker in addUser.jsp

Comment: thanks . i tried but not work fine for me.... i find another solution . i am using in build datetimepicker ...but in another case ..might be this problem arise again ....when we forward the request it don't reload all resources but using redirect i will take the round-trip time to load the page....